# GPS configure for Navit

Tags: 14.04, configuration, gps

I need to connect my USB GPS device to Navit that runs on Ubuntu. I have done:

```
gpsd /dev/ttyUSB0
```

and then run `xgps` to test GPS device. I see some satellites and data on screen.

Now I would like to connect GPS to Navit. I have line in navit.xml file:

```
        <vehicle name="Local GPS" profilename="car" enabled="yes" active="1" source="gpsd://localhost" gpsd_query="w+xj">
```

But I don't see point on Navit screen. Looks that existence of GPS device has no influence on my Navit. How to test Navit is connected to GPS? What is might be wrong with my Navit connection to GPS?

Answer (score 2):

## Works for Navit and other GIS software, such as kismet.

Edit `/etc/default/gpsd` file in terminal :

```
sudo nano /etc/default/gpsd
```

The file must have the following contents

```
START_DAEMON="true"
USBAUTO="true"
DEVICES="/dev/ttyUSB0"
GPSD_OPTIONS="/dev/ttyUSB0"
GPSD_SOCKET=”/var/run/gpsd.sock”
```